# Как посчитать значение выражения, представленного строкой, и вывести его?

Tags: java

Дело в том, что мне нужно решить задачи, у которых тип данных `String`

Например:

```
String bla = "5 + 10 - 5";
SystemOutPrintln(Integer.parseInt(bla));
```

Мне нужно получить ответ, например `10`. Но, вариант выше выведет ошибку, так как символы `+` и `-` не являются целыми числами.

Как можно решить такого рода задачи, или есть другие варианты, буду признателен за дельные советы?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Нужно посчитать значение выражения, представленного строкой, и вывести его?

Comment: Sv__t, Да, все верно!

Comment: какие операторы могу содержаться в строке?

Comment: Тогда Вам понадобится что-то вроде https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, Плюс(+), Минус(-), Деление(/) и умножение(*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно несколько вариантов решения:

1. Написать свой интерпретатор
2. Подключить готовый интерпретатор, например [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/)
3. Подключить ScriptEngine, например JavaScript (вариант использования https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423360/690987)
4. Преобразовать выражение в java-код (на лету), скомпилировать и выполнить его
5. Сгенерировать байт-код, используя библиотеку генерации байт-кода, и выполнить его, например [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/)

Comment: Спасибо, Script Engine очень помогло!