# Как преобразовать строку с математическим выражением в часть выполняемого кода?

Tags: java

Возможно ли преобразовать строку с математическим выражением в часть кода следующим образом:
Существует переменная типа String, которая инициализирована следующим: `x*x*x`.
В коде есть некоторый метод, который работал бы следующим образом:

```
public double someMethod(String s)
{
return (число, полученное вычислением выражения, которое содержится в вышеуказанной переменной);
}
```

Если такое возможно, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Самое простое решение, это использовать такие библиотеки как этот https://github.com/APISENSE/rhino-android

Comment: другие дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778864/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678140/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780858/178576), и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java 8..11 Можно использовать JavaScript-движок Nashorn, впрочем он был помечен как deprecated в Java 11 и окончательно удалён в Java 15.

Данный движок поддерживает знаменитую функцию [`eval`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.scripting/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String)), выполняющую JavaScript на Java, тогда требуемый метод может выглядеть так:

```java
private static final ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
    .getEngineByName("nashorn");

public static double foo(double x) {
    String script =  "var x = " + x + ";";
    String fun = "x * x * x";
    try {
        return (double) engine.eval(script + fun);
    } catch (ScriptException screx) { // convert checked exception to Runtime
        throw new RuntimeException(screx);
    }
}
```

Или даже можно определить функцию в джаваскрипте и подставить в её вызов значение `x`:

```java
public static double bar(double x) {
    String script = "function f(x) { return x * x * x} f(" + x + ");";
    try {
        return (double) engine.eval(script);
    } catch (ScriptException screx) {
        throw new RuntimeException(screx);
    }
}
```

Результаты:

```java
System.out.println("foo(3) = " + foo(3)); // foo(3) = 27.0
System.out.println("bar(2) = " + bar(2)); // bar(2) = 8.0
```

Comment: eval is evil, но в данной ситуации мне придется им воспользоваться, спасибо Вам большое!